# URLRewriting in c# asp .net

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to implement custom url rewriting I followed like MVC default routing concept but I am unable to get the result. C an any one tell me how to do It

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: FYI, "ASP.NET" is one word, with no spaces.

Comment: @Vikcia: Yes, I'm sure. It's been one word since about 2001.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are trying to do this on your own, instead of implimenting an already feature rich and battle tested library like:

[Managed Fusion Url Rewriter](http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/)

There is even a [NuGet Package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/ManagedFusion.Rewriter) to make the install easier:

```
PM> Install-Package ManagedFusion.Rewriter
```

Answer (score 0):

For example this [way](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx).